# Swagger Structure For Interface with Enums

Tags: typescript, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am trying to find the swagger structure of the interface having fields as an integer as well as an array of an integer as fields.

Not able to figure out how the handle the int and array of int simultaneously.

So far i have tried this:

```
DataType:
   discriminator: _class
     properties:
     _class:
       type: string
   enum:
     - string
     - integer
```

The interface is:

```
DataType {
  params: {
    [name: string]: int | string | int[] | string[] 
  }
}
```